# How can I create countdown in oracle apex

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle-apex

How can I create a **countdown** in Oracle Apex? I work on an online exam system and I want on the first question page to have a specific time and after this time has ended if the question is answered or not answered then go to the second question, I designed the pages and did the functions To display the question and options in front of the user.
**For example:**
after two minutes, I want to close a page and go to a page.
I want to help .. and thank you very much.

Comment: IMO, the countdown can be handled from front-end. You can sent the start time and end time in front-end and it can do the rest you mentioned. The only thing you can do in Oracle is make validations when user's time is up or it has made a selection.

Comment: How can I do that?

Comment: Maybe have a look at this plug-in to start: https://apex.world/ords/f?p=100:710:::::P710_PLG_ID:COM.FARZAD.APEX.FLIP.COUNT

Comment: I know this,
But how is counting down, not counting upward?